# Create shortcut similar to holding "super"

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

Is it possible to create a keyboard shortcut similar to holding the super key? 
I would like to map holding a key (holding alt for example) to display an overlay image of my choosing. Is this possible with Unity/Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: what means display an overlay image of your choosing? Please specify more.

Comment: When you hold 'super' on unity, an image (a list of the keyboard shortcuts) comes up on top of all windows open and it goes away as soon as you let go of 'super'. What I want is a shortcut that does the exact same thing, but with a different key and a different image (say hold 'alt' and have a list of the vim commands come up on the screen)